# PHP Required Files Iron Worker

Tags: php, heroku, ironworker

I am uploading a .worker file to ironworker. The worker's code requires (with the require command) other php files. Do I need to upload them too to ironworker?

In other words, do I need to add something else to the .worker file and how:

```
# define the runtime language
runtime "php"
# exec is the file that will be executed:
exec "hello.php"
```

WHERE: hello.php would contain this statement:

```
require_once 'bye.php';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. IronWorker runs on Iron.io's servers, so all dependencies need to be uploaded.

You can do this in the worker file by using the `dir` and `file` commands:

```
dir 'path/to/dir'
file 'path/to/file.php'
```

Dir will include entire directories, file will include only a single file. You can find out more information on the [.worker reference page](http://dev.iron.io/worker/reference/dotworker).